# DHCP Config for Server 2012 R2

Tags: dhcp, windows-server-2012-r2, dhcp-server

This question may have been covered before, but it is rather complex and haven't found a similar post, so please be kind!

I think my issue is rather unique, so I'll try to explain as best I can.

I'm currently configuring a domain at home for my new lab setup. I want my network setup as such,

> My network is a `192.168.0.0/23` with all clients sporting the `255.255.254.0` subnet mask.
>
> > `192.168.0.0/24` for servers. - DHCP handing out addresses.
> >
> > `192.168.1.0/24` for clients. - DHCP handing out addresses.

I believe that it's possible for the DHCP Server to distinguish the difference between the two types of clients with a DHCP Client ID. I want the servers to use a select ID without the need for clients to use one.

If you believe this isn't possible, but do know of any software / OS that may support this kind of setup please advice me. I'm not holding out much hope here, I'd just love to see if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: To clarify: are you using a single network or two ones? If the latter, you will need a router configured for DHCP relay and two DHCP scopes on the server (which will be connected to only one of the networks). Otherwise, your description is wrong: if you only have one network, all computers will use a /23 subnet mask, regardless of having 0 or 1 in the third octet.

Answer (score 0):

Passing out DHCP leases based on more than just the client MAC address is very common. The best examples of how this is done are in the dhcpd.conf file that [DRBL](http://drbl.org) configures.  An example from the [DRBL FAQ](http://drbl.org/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/37_coexist_with_existing_dhcp.faq#37_coexist_with_existing_dhcp.faq):

```
class "DRBL-Client" { 
match if 
(substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 9) = "PXEClient") or 
(substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 9) = "Etherboot") or 
(substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 10) = "DRBLClient"); 
}
```

Note the DHCP codes and then enter those examples to setup windows.  However, based on experience of Windows losing reservations, i would use dhcpd on Linux or an equivalent BSD.  Windows DHCP is not easier to configure as it small sized dialogs to configure a long laundry list of options.  Searching for a hostname, IP address, MAC, or other client identification does not exist in Windows, but easy to search the dhcpd.conf text file.  If you are stuck with Windows DHCP, then you have to use powershell to *try* to keep sane.